# zsh shortcut 'ctrl + A' not working

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, shortcut

I recently switch from bash to zsh shell. To be more precise, the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)
Very nice, but the shortcut I most often use; jumping to the beginning/end of the line doesn't work anymore. From the [docs](http://www.geekmind.net/2011/01/shortcuts-to-improve-your-bash-zsh.html) it should be

```
ctrl + A --> beginning
ctrl + E --> end
```

However, when I do that I get the following

```
$~> my-command
$~> my-command^A   # did a ctrl + A here
```

Although I see this working by everybody else, on my system something seems to be different. Any suggestions what that might be ?

Comment: Check if `bindkey | fgrep '^A'` returns a line like ""^A" beginning-of-line".

Comment: if I do that I get for Ctrl+A: `"^A"-"^C" self-insert` and for Ctrl+E: `"^E"-"^F" self-insert`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you don't have to config the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> behavior if you use default keymap (`emacs` keymap). It does what you are expecting.

However if you set your zle to use `vi` keymap, you have to define the `keybind` for `vi-beginning-of-line`. same for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

So check which keymap did you set in config. If it was vi, try pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> then <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>$</kbd> should do what you want.

Comment: Any suggestions how to check this ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri you don't know which keymap you are using ?  `bindkey -v ` bind vi, `bindkye -e` binds emacs

Comment: what would be the preferred way to define this system wide (mac) ? For a specific user is also ok if that is easier ? Now if I open a new terminal I have to this this binding again

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri write it in your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: If I add something like this to my .zshrc it doesn't work: `bindkey -e
`. So should I export something maybe ?

Comment: Very likely you have Bindkey -v you letter find and remove it. Or you put -e at the end of your config

Comment: couldn't find it, but when I put that command at the end of .zshrc it works! thnx!

Answer (score 55):

If you're wondering why this happened: You likely have `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` set to vi/vim which made zsh default to the vi keymap which doesn't use ctrl+a for moving the caret.

Adding `bindkey -e` to `~/.zshrc` will restore the old behavior (emacs keymap).

Comment: This was it for me. in fact I didn't even have `$VISUAL` set to `vi`, I had it set to a command which opened an IDE and the path happened to contain _the word_ `visual` ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with VSCode/zsh embedded terminal not respecting `^A`/`^E`. I found other hints to make these keys work for iTerm2, but that involved changing how iTerm2 behaves rather than fixing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 17):

zsh .zshrc

```
bindkey "^A" vi-beginning-of-line
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for people that want to keep the vim keymap.  Use `bindkey "^E" vi-end-of-line` to map ctrl + E to the end of line behavior.